# How should I use "so" and" too" for implying "That's also true for me" in this example?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

This is a conversation between two friends, one is 30 the other is 25. They are speaking about their school time:

**First conversation:**

> A: Do you remember Mr. X? He was my English teacher.
>
> B: Oh, yes. He was my English teacher too.

I want to use "so" or "too" in a short sentence (B's sentence) to show [agreement with a positive statement](https://www.espressoenglish.net/so-neither-too-how-to-agree-in-english/).

---

I know if the conversation was as follows, I could use "I was too." or     "So was I":

**Second conversation:**

> A: Do you remember Mr. X? I was his student.
>
> B: Oh, yes. I was his student too./ I was too./ So was I.(And informally: Me too./ Ditto.)

But I don't know how B can use this grammar to express their agreement with A, in the **first conversation.**

PS:

**If this grammar is not applicable to the first conversation, how should B express their agreement (i.e. "That's also true for me.") in a short form?** (formally or informally)

Comment: *He was mine too*! *So* does not really apply here.

Comment: I see. @WS2. How about "me too"? Can B use that?

Comment: B can say "Mine, too" or "Mine also". I agree with WS2 that *so* doesn't really work here - "So he was" means that B agrees that Mr X was A's English teacher.

Comment: @Lawrence, thanks. Regarding WS2's comment and yours,  I think that grammar is not applicable to the fisrt conversation.  I just found " Same" and "Likewise", can I use them as short yet complete answers in this case?

Comment: @Soudabeh Yes, *likewise* is idiomatic (but sounds more BrE than AmE); *same* is more colloquial but also common.

Comment: @Soudabeh *Me too* doesn't really work, because you need the possessive *mine*. Had A have said *I had Mr X as my English teacher*, then you could say *me too*. *Likewise* is alright in everyday speech, and is often used, but it is not good formal English. There is no grammatical base for it.

Comment: I see, @WS2.Thanks for your explanation. (I just felt that I could not use that grammar but I didn't know why). Actually, I like to know all possible formal and also informal answers to this question. I think they would be useful for English-learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second conversation does not flout any of grammatical rules of eliding and is correct in its formal/ informal avatars.

The first conversation is our problem area. It is proposed that B wants to skid  most of the words by restricting the answer to bare minimum. We call it Answer Ellipses. Ellipses come from Greek meaning 'to leave'. In our day to day conversation words are left out of a sentence, but the sentence can still be meaningful and in such an elliptical construction of answer, redundancies are left out when context is of real help.

But we must be careful the Answer Ellipsis can satisfy the identity requirement(  parallelism) needed to license deletion for likeness of form enable the reader/ person spoken to recognize the likeness of content and function.
@Lawrence suggested the  best possible grammatically correct alternatives.

- Mine, too.
- So of mine.
- Mine, also. or any other form as:-
- Yes, I do, incidently my teacher too.

In answer ellipses or dialogues we can skid the whole of sentence except a word or two. Symmetry only matters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer@ Barid Baran Acharya.  Can B use 'Ditto' or 'Same here' as colloquial replies, too? ( I mean in the first conversation.)

Comment: @Soudabeh I am afraid, we should not.These are informal in tone and correspond to either of the two sentences of A, not both. Add a bit of your imagination to them. To me- for me- should be suffixed to make it meaningful.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, @Barid Baran Acharya. Thanks again. :)